# Uses of Cantors intersection theorem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Cantors intersection theorem states :

If $\cdots\subset C_3 \subset C_2 \subset C_1$ is a decreasing sequence of non-empty sequentially compact subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, then the intersection of these sets is non-empty.

My question :

How does one use this theorem to prove properties of metric spaces. specifically does it help at all in proofs regarding showing a set is  open/closed , complete or compact ?

Edit: I merely wish to know is it possible to use it tro prove any of these properties, as it is a proof I learned in my metric spaces class but I can not find an immediate use for it nor have I seen it used in any proofs I have come across regarding properties of metric spaces. So I wanted to know if this was perhaps just thrown in to prepare for point set topology where it may become more useful or is it useful now and I just haven't realised yet in what way (Edit after 2 votes to close because the question seemed too broad)

Comment: It's often used as a method of finding limit points, and the like. It can be used for a lot of things

Comment: Check out Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem and Heine-Borel Theorem

Comment: @RushabhMehta well the Bolzano-weirstrauss  theorem states that any bounded sequence of real numbers contains a convergent subsequence ( and if we further this to a closed subset then it also coverges in the subset ) . The heine-borel theorem states that any closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact. But I simply don't see how these connect to the cantor intersection theorem. Is it because if they are sequentially compact then by heine borel they must be closed and bounded subsets and then by the bolzano weirstrauss theorem every sequence in these sets must converge ?

Comment: Maybe I should just ask can I totally avoid this theorem without much detriment to being able to prove the properties I've mentioned because I find it rather difficult to think of a way to use in a proof

Answer (score 2):

One usage that I like is to prove a theorem from Sierpinski. Namely **The Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$ is not the union of disjoint circles**.

The idea of the proof is to proceed by contradiction and to find a sequence of decreasing closed disks such that the next one has a radius less than half of the previous one. The intersection of those disks is not empty according to Cantor’s intersection theorem, and is reduced to a single point. A circle can’t pass through this intersection point.

Cantor’s intersection theorem can also be used to prove that Cantor set is not empty.

*Not sure this is what you are looking for though...*

Comment: ah okay so taking what you said about proving that  $\Bbb R^2$ is not the union of disjoint circles can cantors theorem be used in other proofs regarding seperabilty ?

Comment: sorry I meant to say connected

Comment: More generally, let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. A non-empty $Y\subset X$ is bounded iff $\sup_{u,v\in Y}d(u,v)<\infty.$ If  $(C_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a  decreasing sequence of non-empty  closed bounded subsets of $X$ then $\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n\ne \emptyset.$..This is used to prove  the widely-used Baire Category Theorem: If $D=\{D_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ is a family of dense open subsets of $X$ then $\cap D$ is dense ... Also used to prove, if  $X$ is not empty and has no isolated points, then $X$ has a sub-space homeomorphic to the Cantor set.